# Set General Field on a Component to specific word when the Component is saved

Tags: 2013, event-system

I want to set a General Field (Simple Text Field) on a Component to specific word (ex. "aaa") when the Component is saved, by using Event System.

I success to do the above, but I have one problem.

If the General Field is **not** Mandatory, it's no problem.

But if the General Field is Mandatory, it's problem, that is, the component isn't saved because of displaying error message "Mandatory field "xxx" is missing a value".

One solution is I set the General Field to **not** Mandatory.

But I want to set the General Field to Mandatory.

So please tell me a solution, that is,

how to set a General Field to specific word before SDL Tridion check whether the General Field is missing a value or not, using event system.

**UPDATE2**

the below code is my code.

```
    private void Subscribe()
    {
        EventSubscription subScription = EventSystem.Subscribe<Component, SaveEventArgs>(copys, EventPhases.Initiated);
        _subScriptions.Add(subScription);
    }

    private void copys(Component component, SaveEventArgs args, EventPhases phases)
    {
        if (!component.Schema.Title.Equals("copy_test")) return;

        ItemFields generalFields = new ItemFields(component.Content, component.Schema);

        foreach (ItemField child in generalFields) 
        {
            if (child.Name=="copy") 
            {
                TextField text = (TextField)child;
                text.Value = "set the value";
            }
        }
        component.Content = generalFields.ToXml();
    }
```

Comment: What event phase are you listening to?  Initiated?

Comment: While I do prefer some defaults for authors, I see the Event System as just one technical solution to the requirement. In addition to defaults on schema fields (or a default keyword that you can change), you could consider copy and paste, Experience Manager Page Types, or Custom Content Types. The idea would make the set of options ("aaa") easily changed, or even changed after-the-fact. Is the field really "aaa?" :-)

Comment: >robrtc.. Thank you answer my question. Event phase is Initiated and SaveEventArgs.

Comment: >Alvin Reyes... Thank you answer my question. the above specific word is a example. Many simple text field are set automatically. And I confirm whether this can be or not by Event System.(Especially, the simple text field is mandatory.)

Comment: Default value in schema?

Comment: >  Nuno Linhares.... Thank you answer my question. Yes,

Comment: "Default values" are a Tridion Schema feature. I think Nuno is literally suggesting you can check the `Default Value` option in the Schema in the Content Manager Explorer. You can set a default value for any type of Tridion field so that it will have that value when authors create or edit Components based on that schema (that don't have values filled in).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you are hooking into the **Processed** (or later) phase of the *Save* operation, which will only be called after the save has happened.

You should instead hook into the **Initiated** phase of the save. This one occurs *before* the save and so giving the field a value will satisfy the mandatory requirement of the field when the save does occur.

**Update**: I feel kind of silly for not noticing this before, but this will never work *in the CME*, if the field is mandatory. It's not a problem with your event handler: the CME also does client-side validation and that is what is preventing your save in the first place.

Comment: Thank you answer to my question. I hook the Initiated phase of the save (component). But display the above error message.

Comment: I don't think you're doing it right, then, if you are still getting an error about the field missing a value. Either it's a different field, a different casing of the letters, or you're not setting the value correctly. You'll need to post your actual code for us to help further then.

Comment: Thank you answer to my question.  I update, I show a part of my code. the EventPhases is initiated.

Comment: That's not enough to help you; we need the code that actually sets the field value too.

Comment: Thank you answer to my question. I update, I show my code.

Comment: After re-reading your question, I realized that your issue is probably with the CME's validation stopping you. See the update to my answer.

Comment: Thank you answer to my question. That is, the CME's validation is processed before the event system is processed ? Maybe this is the design. So, If the field is mandatory, it's need to fill the field before processing event system. Is my understanding right ?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps you can do this through a GUI extension - and thus better inform a user that a value was entered. I presume you're aware that fields can have 'default' values already - which may negate your code even running in many instances?

The best way to approach this (event system, GUI extensions, user process/education) will likely depend on the specifics of 'why' you want populate something, just a couple of quick questions that spring to mind are
 - are you writing the value irrespective of the user entry (if so, then perhaps this should be a read-only field [read a.n.other GUI extension])
 - are you wanting to inform the user they entered something invalid / null

Rob has a nice example of this [here](http://www.curlette.com/?p=913) and there's a good discussion of the different options from [Nuno](http://nunolinhares.blogspot.be/2012/07/validating-content-on-save-part-1-of.html)

Comment: Thank you answer to my question.　I want to set a Simple Text Field on a Component to specific word (ex. "abc") only. If the text field is not Mandatory, I know that I can do by Event System. Even if the Text Field is not read-only field, Event System set a specific word.

Answer (score 2):

Though I am not sure, but I doubt the objects (Components etc.) will restore their values across events. I suspect in the code above, you may need to call the `Component.Save` method explicitly once you change the content value of the component - After this statement:

`component.Content = generalFields.ToXml();`

try putting the

`component.Save();`

and check.

Comment: Thank you answer my question. I do the above . But I don't solve the problem.